# Fast multiple search and replace in Perl

Tags: perl

I have a file: `map.txt` - which is having 1000+ lines like below format:

```
aaa { 123 };
bbb { 4567 };
cc { 89 };
```

I have another file `input.txt` having 5 Million+ lines;
which contains aaa as `"aaa"`, bbb as `"bbb"` format.

Can I get a suggestion for a fastest method in perl to search & replace all occurrence of:
`"aaa"` with `"123"`
`"bbb"` with `"4567"` so on.

Comment: Use a hash. Pretty straightforward, unless you have nested quotes.

Comment: See also follow-up discussion: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25579821/perl-not-matching-multiple-hash-keys-comes-in-a-single-line

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a hash. Use the old strings as keys, replacement strings as values.

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use warnings;
use strict;

my %map;
open my $MAP, '<', 'map.txt' or die $!;
while (<$MAP>) {
    my ($pattern, $replacement) = /(.*) { (.*) };/;
    $map{$pattern} = $replacement;
}

open my $IN, '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;
while (<$IN>) {
    s/"(.*)"/"$map{$1}"/g;
    print;
}
```

To output to a new file, change the last paragraph as follows:

```
open my $IN,  '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;
open my $OUT, '>', 'output.txt' or die $!;
while (<$IN>) {
        s/"(.*?)"/exists $map{$1} ? qq{"$map{$1}"} : qq{"$1"}/ge;
    print {$OUT} $_;
}
close $OUT;
```

Comment: 2nd section is printing properly on screen; but I want to redirect to output.txt, not working properly for me. Either getting same 'output.txt' as 'input.txt', or some extra empty replacements are getting for those variable not mentioned in 'map.txt'. Could you please update the code to redirect to 'output.tx' properly?

Comment: @Brijesh: Do you mean that if you run `map.pl > output.txt`, it doesn't work?

Comment: not like that, in fact i havn't tried that & can't be since this section is a part of a big perl program. I need the output of this section as 'output.txt' to proceed further..

Comment: Thanks, this is even i tried before ur update; but sorry to tell that it is not correctly generating. It is modifying all the 1000+ from map.txt; but as i mentioned in my previous mail, it is even try to modify variables not mentioned in map.txt. for example, "tck" modifying correctly as "cplk"; but "fll" (which is not given in map.txt) also modified as "" (null)- which should not. Also getting 'Use of uninitialized value in concatenation (.) or string at ../macro_mapped_wgl_generation.pl' line s/"(.*)"/"$map{$1}"/g;

Comment: @Brijesh: My fault. Fixed now.

Comment: There is a corner case exist: there is a single line in 'input.txt' contains "aaa","bbb","cc" etc. There our scripts doesn't modify with its hash values! What can be added in our program to cover this issue. help is very much appreciated.

Comment: @Brijesh: Check the update again. Next time, maybe try some programming yourself.

Comment: @Brijesh: Works for me for a line `"aaa", "bbb", "cc"`.

Comment: Am using perl v5.6.1 ! is that hint anything

Answer (score 1):

You should use a trie (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Trie).

A module is available on CPAN: http://search.cpan.org/~avif/Tree-Trie-1.5/Trie.pm although implementation is really simple.

Answer (score 0):

Possibly something like this:

```
#!/usr/bin/env perl
use strict;
use warnings;

my %hash = (
   aaa => '123',
   bbb => '4567',
   cc  => '89',
)

open FILE, '>', 'input.txt';
while(<FILE>)
{
    if(/"([a-z]+)"/) {
        s/"$1"/'"'.$hash{$1}.'"'/ge if($hash{$1});
    }
}
```

Comment: `'"'.$hash{$1}.'"'` better written `qq("$hash{$1}")`. But why use evaluation at all, its not a very good idea, and not needed: `"hash{$1}"`