# perl: not matching multiple hash keys comes in a single line

Tags: perl

This code is to search & replace using hash. But there is an issue:

```
my %map = (
   abc => '123',
   def => '4567',
   gh  => '89',
);
open my $IN,  '<', 'input.txt' or die $!;
open my $OUT, '>', 'output.txt' or die $!;
while (<$IN>) { 
   s/"(.*?)"/exists $map{$1} ? qq{"$map{$1}"} : qq{"$1"}/ge; 
   print {$OUT} $_; 
}
```

input.txt contains abc as "abc", def as "def" format:

```
"abc" : wxyz 
"def" : pqmn
"gh" : qwerty
MAIN ("abc", "gh", "def", .etc )`
```

The above code: `s/"(.*?)"/exists $map{$1} ? qq{"$map{$1}"} : qq{"$1"}/ge;` modify `input.txt` to `output.txt` but not touching the last line i mentioned.

What an getting `output.txt` is:

```
"123" : wxyz 
"4567" : pqmn
"89" : qwerty
MAIN ("abc", "gh", "def", .etc )
```

But what am expecting is:

```
"123" : wxyz 
"4567" : pqmn
"89" : qwerty
MAIN ("123", "89", "4567", .etc )
```

What is wrong with the above code?

Updated with part of original `input.txt`  as per @Miller

```
signal 
 "abc" : input;
 "def" : input;
 "hijk" : input;
timeplate "scan_cycle" period 
 "abc" := input PQ;
 "hijk" := input RS;
 "def" := input TU;
scan 
"def", 
"hijk", "abc", "gh",
```

what am getting `output.txt`

```
signal 
 "123" : input;
 "4567" : input;
 "hijk" : input;
timeplate "scan_cycle" period 
 "123" := input PQ;
 "hijk" := input RS;
 "4567" := input TU;
scan 
"4567", 
"hijk", "abc", "gh",
```

But what I want `output.txt` , last 'scan' section

```
scan 
"4567", 
"hijk", "123", "89",
```

Comment: Nothing wrong with your code https://eval.in/185673

Comment: If you lied to us and `MAIN` is really a longer string with an unpaired double quote, that would exhibit this behavior.

Comment: Your updated sample still fails to reproduce the problem. https://eval.in/185683

Comment: Am using perl v5.6.1 ! is that hint anything

Comment: No, that would not make a difference. Though that's really, really old. (The `//` hack in @Miller's answer would not work on this old version I believe.)

Answer (score 2):

The code that you're using should be work for the data you provided, so I suspect you are not providing us with all the information.

However, I would suggest making either of these two potential improvements:

- Do exact matching on the keys instead of global `.*?`
- Use lookahead for the ending quote delimiter so that you can test between all double quotes.

Both of these fixes are meant to address the possibility of a stray double quote.

The second fix demonstrated below:

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my %map = (
    abc => '123',
    def => '4567',
    gh  => '89',
);

#open my $infh, '<', 'input.txt';
my $infh = \*DATA;
#open my $outfh, '>', 'output.txt';
my $outfh = \*STDOUT;

while (<$infh>) {
    s{"\K([^"]*)(?=")}{$map{$1} // $1}ge;
    print $outfh $_;
}

__END__
"abc" : wxyz 
"def" : pqmn
"gh" : qwerty
MAIN ("abc", "gh", "def", .etc )
```

Outputs:

```
"123" : wxyz
"4567" : pqmn
"89" : qwerty
MAIN ("123", "89", "4567", .etc )
```

Comment: I'm not sure you have fixed unpaired quotes still. The simple and obvious workaround would be to create a suitable regex out of `join('|', keys %map)` instead.

Comment: Yes, that's option 1.  I chose option 2 because it has the side benefit of tightening the regex code as well by not needing to include the quotes in the RHS.

Comment: I like the tighter regex but it could still fail if the quotes are out of whack. You can wrap the `join`ed regex similarly and be sure it matches and substitutes only exactly the listed keys.

Comment: As a simple test case, replace `MAIN` with `"multi-\nline"` with a literal newline there.

Comment: Given the context if the OP's [earlier question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/25565932/1733163) that led to their current code, I believe there's no reason to expect needing to support keys that span lines.  It's therefore sufficient to just make sure that all groups of characters between quotes on a single line are tested, which either of my proposed fixes would do.

Comment: @Miller, FYI: I even tried `s/"(.*)"/exists $map{$1} ? qq{"$map{$1}"} : qq{"$1"}/ge;` getting the same result. The `input.txt` is a 1GB file. I just given a very small example here. Even the script doesn't work for a small line: `"abc", "gh"` I think when two hash keys comes in the same line, not working.

Comment: @Miller, ur 2nd option is also not working for me; giving the same result i have pasted in original.

Comment: Greedy matching `.*` would not be a solution to any potential problem.

Comment: @Brijesh how about providing **relevant input data**? Your question is really poor in that sense.

Comment: Thanks for the pointer to the earlier question. The OP should have linked to it...

Comment: @Brijesh mpapec has [*showed you*](https://eval.in/185673) in a comment to your question how the code and data you provide DOES work.  So if it's not working on your system there is something that you're not sharing with us.  Perhaps, there's a stray quote like my solution was intended to address.  Perhaps the encoding of the files is wrong, so you're not actually working with a double quote but some weird unicode character.  We can't say with the information that you've provided.

Comment: please find updated Qn, from part of original code. I think when two hash keys comes in the same line, not working

Comment: but am using perl v5.6.1

Comment: That is a very old version of perl.  I would strongly recommend upgrading.  For a simpler regex, perhaps the following: `s/([^"]+)/$map{$1} || $1/eg;`

Answer (score 0):

Given that your code fails to exhibit the problem you are describing with the input data you have supplied, this is really speculative (and in fact I have voted to close this question for that reason) so I'm not too happy about posting this here, but...

Try

```
my $keys = join ('|', map { quotemeta($_) } keys %map);
my $re = qr{"($keys)"};
```

And then later on inside the loop,

```
    s/$re/"$map{$1}"/g;
```

This should be faster as well as robust against unpaired quotes.

Comment: this also gives me the same results !!